# Gitlab CI: How can I select 'include' ref dynamically?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need include yml file with logic that if branch with same name exist in other project then include yml from this branch, else include yml from master branch.

Is there a way to make that?
I think about using dynamic variable, but I don't know how to set it before include and after access to triggered ref name

```
include:
  - project: my_other_project
    ref: $branch_name_that_equals_current_branch_or_master_branch
    file: my.yml
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Check the links provided there to get an overview which variables can be used here and which cannot.

Comment: I'm looking for the same -- did you find anything helpful in the meantime?

Comment: @gxx, no. I provide enviroment variable by hands or script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check which variable you are using**. According to the docs you can only use certain variables like predefined variables or those set manually when triggering the pipeline. Unfortunately you cannot use variables defined in the `variables` block.

So, your example will work if you use one of the variables mentioned [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-variables-with-include).

```
include:
  - project: my_other_project
    ref: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    file: my.yml
```

For instance.

---

See

- [Use variables with include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-variables-with-include)
- [Where variables can be used](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html)

Comment: I hoped that there was at least a hack, but look like it really not possible like I want. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

In your yaml file

```
variables:
  REF: master

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  only:
    refs:
      - $REF
  script:
    - echo "Building branch $REF"
```

Comment: This does not solve the Question: We need to know if a dynamic reference is possible in the context of `include`.